# how to align hypen

Tags: grep, text-formatting, cut, nl

This is my command

```
echo -e  "Test sur la vie, l'univers et le reste \n " >test42 |grep '42' questions.txt | nl -w1  -s '  - ' | cut -d "/" -f 1 >> test42
```

this is the output

```
Test sur la vie, l'univers et le reste 

1  - Quel est le numéro de la dernière armure de Tony Stark dans le film Iron Man 3 ?
2  - Quel est l’angle visuel entre la partie colorée d’un arc-en-ciel et le point central de son arc ?
3  - Quel est le score maximal réalisable à titre individuel au cours des Olympiades internationales de mathématiques ?
4  - À combien de gallons un baril de pétrole est-il équivalent ?
5  - Quel est le nombre d’années de mariage des noces de nacre ?
6  - Quelle est la résistance mécanique en GPa du graphène ?
7  - Combien d'éclipses de soleil et de lune durant un saros ?
8  - Quel est le numéro de l’inode du répertoire root dans un système de fichier reiser4 ?
9  - Combien la Bible de Gutenberg comporte de lignes de texte par colonne ?
10  - Quel est le titre de l'épisode 3X07 de la série télévisée Doctor Who ?
11  - Quel est le numéro atomique du molybdène, un métal de transition ?
```

But the result should be like this

```
Test sur la vie, l'univers et le reste

1  - Quel est le numéro de la dernière armure de Tony Stark dans le film Iron Man 3 ?
2  - Quel est l’angle visuel entre la partie colorée d’un arc-en-ciel et le point central de son arc ?
3  - Quel est le score maximal réalisable à titre individuel au cours des Olympiades internationales de mathématiques ?
4  - À combien de gallons un baril de pétrole est-il équivalent ?
5  - Quel est le nombre d’années de mariage des noces de nacre ?
6  - Quelle est la résistance mécanique en GPa du graphène ?
7  - Combien d'éclipses de soleil et de lune durant un saros ?
8  - Quel est le numéro de l’inode du répertoire root dans un système de fichier reiser4 ?
9  - Combien la Bible de Gutenberg comporte de lignes de texte par colonne ?
10 - Quel est le titre de l'épisode 3X07 de la série télévisée Doctor Who ?
11 - Quel est le numéro atomique du molybdène, un métal de transition ?
12 - Quelle est la taille, en mètre, de l'obélisque inachevé dans la carrière d'Assouan en Égypte ?
```

I need to have 2 spaces between the number 1 to 9 and the hypen. But i need to have only 1 space between the hypen and number 10 and more.

Do you guys have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: why don't you just put a space in front of the single digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want `nl` to *left justify*, with a field width of 3:

```
... | nl -nln -w3 -s '- '
```

or equivalently a field width of 2 if you want to include a leading space explicitly in the separator string:

```
.... | nl -nln -w2 -s ' - '
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
… | nl -w1 -s '  - ' | …
```

to print the line numbers, you could use `awk` instead and format the string with `printf`:

```
… | awk '{printf "%-2s - %s\n",NR,$0}' | …
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to mind is using (GNU) `sed` like this:

```
sed -E 's/^([1-9])  -/\1   -/'
```

added at the end of your commands, before `>>`.